# how to send batch data to the event hub from the azure function in node js?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to send data to the event hub from the azure function written on node js.
But I'm getting the following error when I send the array of objects without.

```
No events found for 'NSEStockInput'.
Start time: Monday, September 23, 2019, 6:56:00 PM
End time: Monday, September 23, 2019, 6:59:00 PM
Last time arrival: Monday, September 23, 2019, 6:59:08 PM
Diagnostics: Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2019-09-23T13:29:10.4592579Z' and '2019-09-23T13:29:10.4592579Z'. Json input stream should either be an array of objects or line separated objects. Found token type: Null
```

But when I'm JSON.stringify the data I'm getting error as

```
Exception: Error: data is required and it must be of type object.
```

Here the code that I have written

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    const {  EventHubClient, EventData, EventPosition, OnMessage, OnError, MessagingError } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
    const connectionString = connectionString
    var axios = require('axios')
    context.log('ssss')
    const client = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    context.log('sssaaa')
    var response = await axios.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/nifty500StockWatch.json')
    await client.send(JSON.stringify(response['data']['data']))

    context.log('message sent')

};
```

How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

We can find the error message in the [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node/blob/master/client/lib/eventHubSender.ts) of "eventHubSender".

[image]

So this error message means the input data is not an object type, we can search for the details of "JSON.stringify()" method by [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) link and find the return is a string. And according to the first error message you provided

```
Json input stream should either be an array of objects or line separated objects"
```

So I think if you want to input an array of objects, you need to change your code from

```
await client.send(JSON.stringify(response['data']['data']))
```

to

```
await client.send(response['data']['data'])
```

**Update:**

Here is my function code for your reference:

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    const {  EventHubClient, EventData, EventPosition, OnMessage, OnError, MessagingError } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
    const connectionString = "Endpoint=************"
    const eventHubsName = "hurytestentity"
    var axios = require('axios')

    const client = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubsName);
    context.log('sssaaa')
    var response = await axios.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/nifty500StockWatch.json')
    await client.send(response['data']['data'])
    context.log('message sent')

};
```

The code above works fine.

Comment: But, when I use the await client.send(response['data']['data'])
I get error from the Azure stream analytics side while processing the data. The error as follows, Diagnostics: Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2019-09-24T06:21:53.0694279Z' and '2019-09-24T06:21:53.0694279Z'. Json input stream should either be an array of objects or line separated objects. Found token type: Null

Comment: can anyone help with this.

Comment: Hi @sarank, I shared my function code in my answer, the function works fine. Please take a look, it may help your issue.

Comment: By using the code that you have I can able send data to the event hub, But I'm getting an error from azure stream analytics. The error as follows No events found for 'NSEStockInput'.
Diagnostics: Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2019-09-24T07:03:22.9492042Z' and '2019-09-24T07:03:22.9492042Z'. Json input stream should either be an array of objects or line separated objects. Found token type: Null